# How to mask input by regular expressions? either 1112223333 or 1112223333444

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010, xaml

This is within a xaml file.

I need to mask a box's input with a regular expression.

I need it to contain either 10 numbers or 13 numbers (in sequence, with no symbols)

I have :

```
<... ValidationRegEx="\d{13}" />
```

which works fine, but when i want to add a mask of ten in , it breaks :

```
<... ValidationRegEx="\d{13} | \d{10}" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: no spaces in the second Regex?

Comment: Maybe remove space before and after "|" ?

Comment: Please update your question/tags to reflect that this question is about XAML, not C#. Your code snippets should probably also be XAML, not C#

Comment: Thanks Cyborgx37, got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
< ... RegEx="\b\d{10}\b|\b\d{13}\b" ... />
```

This represents "find a whole word with 10 digits or find a whole world with 13 digits".

the \b at front and behind the regex signifies find the whole word.

Check out this tutorial site that helped me answer my own question:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

Comment: @Ωmega , it is not wrong at all.  notice the \d, which signifies digit.

Comment: Wrong! Wrong! Wrong! Test it!

Comment: i had a \w in there instead of a \d.  this has been corrected with the latest version.

Answer (score 8):

I thin the spaces should be removed, like this:

```
ValidationRegEx = "\d{13}|\d{10}"
```

Otherwise, space characters become part of the string that you match (i.e. 13 digits followed by a space, or a space followed by ten digits).

You could also try simplifying the expression like this:

```
ValidationRegEx = "\d{10}\d{3}?"
```

(required ten plus three optional digits).

Comment: what do you mean you double slashed to make valid C# string literals?

Whats the difference between \\d{10}\\d{3}? and \d{10}\d{3}? ?

Comment: @jordan.peoples \ is an escape character. A \\ escapes the escape.

Comment: @jordan.peoples If you create a string literal with a single slash in front of a `"\d"`, [it would not compile](http://ideone.com/3ZxWG) with the following error: "Unrecognized escape sequence `\d'". An alternative would be using a verbatim literal `@"\d{13}|\d{10}"` with the at `@` sign.

Comment: but my initial code worked fine for 10 units.

"\d{13}"

I don't understand why the \\ is needed once i have 2 parts of the regex

Comment: @jordan.peoples Is this XAML by any chance? If so, remove the doubled slashes.

Comment: Ah, ok.  It is xaml. i should have added that. i will add it to the question above

Comment: So \d{10}|\d{13} semi worked.

This lets me have 11 12 or 13 units in the string whereas i need either 10 or 13 , and nothing in between.

Comment: Could you Try adding the anchors to the beginning and to the end of the expression, like this? `"^\d{10}|\d{13}$"`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18134/discussion-between-jordan-peoples-and-dasblinkenlight)

Comment: This didnt work at all.  
 This lets me have 11 12 or 13 units in the string whereas i need either 10 or 13 , and nothing in between.

Comment: @jordan.peoples Ah, OK. It's hard to tell what expression is needed without knowing precisely how it is used internally by the regex engine. You can further optimize your expression to `"\b(\d{10}|\d{13})\b"`

Answer (score 0):

```
                              ┌─────┬─ 10 or 13 digits
                              ↓     ↓
 ValidationRegEx = "(?<!\d)\d{10}\d{3}?(?!\d)" 
                       ↑                 ↑
                       │                 └─ negative lookahead to ensure 
                       │                    there is no other digit ahead
                       │
                       └─ negative lookbehind to ensure
                          there is no other digit behind
```

Comment: that's way to complex.  try this : "\b\d{10}\b|\b\w{13}\b"

Comment: @jordan.peoples - Your solution posted in the comment is wrong. Anyway... I wanted to post an alternative solution using lookarounds, so some users can learn this amazing feature. If I wanted to use boundaries, I would go with `\b\d{10}\d{3}?\b` pattern.

Comment: my way works fine. it is correct and tested already by the QA team.

Comment: @jordan.peoples - What is correct on `\w{13}` part..? It is wrong!